# insert existing file to folder in intellij IDE

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, intellij-idea

Is it possible to insert an existing file in a separate destination folder to project folder in Intellij IDE?

ex: I have `angular.js` in another location I want to get this into project folder.

I'm using Intellij IDE 2016.3 version

Answer (score 0):

In the **Project Structure** (shortcut keys are **command + ;** for mac or **CTRL + ;** for other OS) you should get into the **Artifacts** section and then in the left upper + you can choose the file you wish to insert (if no type match to the file type you have choose **other**). Set the **Output directory** for the path in your computer and press **OK**.